# Comment length for 'voting to close this as off topic because...' is significantly shorter than for standard comments

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comments, close-reasons

I was looking to close a recent question as a shopping request, and there was a standard comment I used to place on questions when doing so, which was:

> Questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and any recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

This is a fine length to be placed as a standard comment on posts. However if I try to use this same text in place of the 'I'm voting to close this as off topic because...' placeholder I am told that my comment is too long by 56 characters.

Why is the close reason comment shorter than a standard comment when they both end up as comments against the question anyway? And can this be extended to match, so that I can reuse my lovely-worded comment when closing these posts.

Comment: Yeah, but even deleting that doesn't give you those free characters back.

Comment: Rene is right - the backing field for custom off-topic reasons in the DB is 500 characters long.

Answer (score 13):

I borrowed the hacker-hat from [nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael) but I don't have high hopes this restriction is just an oversight or to strict client-side validation.

[image: length should be less then 500 chars]

This is the json payload that came back on [the post to close/add](https://meta.stackexchange.com/flags/questions/258856/close/add) when I get rid of the client-side validation:

```js
{"Success":false,
 "Message":"Off-topic > other comments should be between 30 and 500 characters",
 "ResultChangedState":false}
```

The client-side validation has that value of 500 clearly in the `charCounter` initialization:

```js
function close_initOffTopicSubPane()
{
    var div = _closePopup.find('.off-topic-other-comment-container'),
        txt = div.find('textarea'),
        isValid = function(isValid)
        {
            var customValid = isValid && ensureNotInitialValue();
            _closePopup.find('.popup-submit').enable(customValid)
        };
    txt.charCounter({
        target: div.find('.text-counter'), min: 30, max: 500, setIsValid: isValid
    });
```

Where the comment setup for the `charCounter` is set to maximum of 600:

```js
var renderCommentForm = function(jForm, buttonText, showCancel, onSubmit)
{
    var isValid = false;
    var setIsValid = function(bool)
        {
            isValid = bool
        };
    var inputBox = jForm.find('textarea');
    inputBox.charCounter({
        min: 15, max: 600, setIsValid: setIsValid
    }).focus(function()
    {
        StackExchange.comments.tabCompleter.init($(this))
    });
```

Expect this to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), probably because one of the columns holding your custom off-topic reason doesn't have a length capable of accepting more than 500 characters.

Comment: This does seem to be the case for when the comment is initially made. It then becomes a 'normal' comment and, should I so desire, I can then edit the comment to go full-length. Yeah, it's not an end-of-the-world issue here, just a *'hmm, that's weird'* one.

Answer (score 3):

> I am told that my comment is too long by 56 characters.

Ok, I know it's not the *exact* fix to your request, but what about:

> Questions requesting recommendations for books/software/apps etc.
> would fall into the [shopping
> request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
> category and aren't suitable to a Q&A site. This is because there's no
> one correct answer, and any recommended items would soon be updated
> and replaced with newer/better versions making the best answers
> redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such
> discussions, they're not suitable for this main site.

500 chars ;)

Comment: To which OP would reply 'What do you mean shopping request'? ;)

Comment: Ok you win :D I've had to change more, perhaps more than you want. However, looking at rene's comment, it seems it might be status-bydesign, so won't change, so you're going to have to work around it :) I'm sure you can reword yourself, was just giving the example really.

Comment: Yeah, it feels like butchering the grammar of a tweet to try to cram it into 140 characters!

Comment: Hi James! Did you forget the word "is" between "This" and "because" in your second sentence, or is that just me being too verbose? :)

Comment: Hi Sue :) That was an unintentional mistake, well spotted. I trimmed it down but didn't want it that pithy! It also makes it exactly the 500 char limit too!